# SQL Server 2005 - odd clustered index size

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

#### Existing table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [MYTABLE](
    [ROW1] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ROW2] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ROW3] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ROW4] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [MYTABLE_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ROW1] ASC, [ROW2] ASC, [ROW3] ASC)
)
```

This table has 2 non-clustered indexes, and the following stats:

```
RowCount:    5260744
Data Space:  229.609 MB
Index Space: 432.125 MB
```

I wanted to reduce the size of the indexes, and use a surrogate primary key as the clustered index, instead of the natural composite key.

#### New table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_RUN_INFO](
    [ROW1] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ROW2] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ROW3] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ROW4] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [MYTABLE_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
```

Still with only 2 non-clustered indexes, here's the new stats:

```
RowCount:    5260744
Data Space:  249.117 MB
Index Space: 470.867 MB
```

#### Question

Can someone account for how a clustered index using 3 NUMERIC(18,0) columns is smaller than a clustered index using a single INT column?

I rebuilt the indexes before and after the changes, and the fill factor is set to 0 for both structures.

The two non-clustered indexes are the same, and were not changed to include the new ID column.

#### sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats

Stats taken with the ID column

Composite clustered index

```
INDEX   TYPE            DEPTH   LEVEL   PAGECOUNT   RECORDCOUNT RECORDSIZE  
1       CLUSTERED       3       0       31884       5260744     47
1       CLUSTERED       3       1       143         31884       34
1       CLUSTERED       3       2       1           143         34
5       NONCLUSTERED    3       0       27404       5260744     40
5       NONCLUSTERED    3       1       167         27404       46
5       NONCLUSTERED    3       2       1           167         46
6       NONCLUSTERED    3       0       27400       5260744     40
6       NONCLUSTERED    3       1       164         27400       46
6       NONCLUSTERED    3       2       1           164         46
```

INT clustered index

```
INDEX   TYPE            DEPTH   LEVEL   PAGECOUNT   RECORDCOUNT RECORDSIZE  
1       CLUSTERED       3       0       31887       5260744     47
1       CLUSTERED       3       1       54          31887       11
1       CLUSTERED       3       2       1           54          11
5       NONCLUSTERED    4       0       29893       5260744     44
5       NONCLUSTERED    4       1       198         29893       50
5       NONCLUSTERED    4       2       3           198         50
5       NONCLUSTERED    4       3       1           3           50
6       NONCLUSTERED    4       0       29891       5260744     44
6       NONCLUSTERED    4       1       193         29891       50
6       NONCLUSTERED    4       2       2           193         50
6       NONCLUSTERED    4       3       1           2           50
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clustered index leaf pages include all the columns of the table (not just the key columns). By adding a surrogate primary key you have just increased the length of all rows in the leaf pages by 4 bytes. Multiply that out by 5,260,744 rows and that equals an additional 20 MB to store the `ID` column.

The key is narrower however so you may well have fewer non leaf level pages (use `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` to see this) and as the clustered index key is used as the row locator in the non clustered indexes this can make those smaller (but less covering) too.

Comment: If I keep the new ID identity column, but revert back to the composite clustered index, the clustered index size shrinks.

Comment: How are you getting these sizes? What is the output of `USE YOURDB; SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(),OBJECT_ID('YOURTABLE'),NULL,NULL, 'DETAILED')` for both? (Make sure you adjust DB name and table name before running)

Comment: Thanks. I found a few queries on the net to display the index size, as well as right-clicking on the table and going to the storage tab.  They all confirmed the index size had grown.  I've printed out the relevant portions of the sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats view, and put them in my original question.  I'll look it over, but any insight you have on why there's a larger depth/record count on the non-clustered indexes would be great.

Comment: Seems to be the NCIs not the CI that has really grown. Are the NCIs with `indexid` 5 and 6 just `ROW1,ROW2,ROW3` again in different orders? Looks like the key for both of those has increased by 4 bytes too. For Non Unique Non clustered indexes the CI key is added to the NCI key.

Comment: Yep, saw that the CI did shrink, which makes sense.  The NCI's use ROW1, ROW2, ROW3 and ROW4 in different orders.

Comment: @jhsheets - Not in this case. The original CI key is `ROW1,ROW2,ROW3` and as this is already included in the index definition there is no additional penalty for including the CI key as row locator. Changing to a surrogate means you still need all those columns + the `id` column on top. And you don't lose any columns to compensate as they were all in the index definition explicitly to begin with.

Comment: Aaah.  That explains it.  Thanks for your help.